# Independent Discrete random variables.

Tags: probability-theory

I'm reading the David Williams probability book and this exercise caught my attention.  It seems rather tricky and I cant figure it out.

Let $Y_0,Y_1,Y_2,..$ be independent random variables such that $$P(Y_n = 1) = P(Y_n = -1) = \frac 12 \; \; \forall n $$

Consider $X_n = Y_0Y_1Y_2..Y_n $

Show that the $X_n$ are independent. and if we define $$ \mathcal{F} = \sigma(Y_1,Y_2..) , \; \; \mathcal{T}_n= \sigma(X_r : r > n) $$

Show that , $$ \bigcap_{n} \sigma(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{T}_n) \neq \sigma(\mathcal{F}, \bigcap_{n} \mathcal{T}_n ) $$

Honesty I'm not even sure how to begin by showing the $X_n$ are independent. If I pick any finite index $J \subset \mathbb{N}$ and try to show that $\{X_i : i \in J \}$ are independent I get no where either. Is this question difficult or am I just missing something trivial?

**EDIT :**

There's a hint in the text for part 2.

Prove that $Y_0$ is measurable with respect to $\bigcap_{n} \sigma(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{T}_n)$ and that $Y_0$ is Independent of $\sigma(\mathcal{F}, \bigcap_n \mathcal{T}_n ) $

Original picture from text :

[image]

Comment: The independence part seems easier to me, you want to show that for all relevant $(x_0, ..., x_n)$, the following expression decomposes as a product: $$Pr[X_n=x_n, X_{n-1}=x_{n-1}, ..., X_0=x_0]$$ You can recursively condition, start by: $$Pr[X_n=x_n, ..., X_0=x_0] = Pr[X_n=x_n|X_{n-1}=x_{n-1}, ..., X_0=x_0]Pr[X_{n-1}=x_{n-1}, ..., X_0=x_0]$$

Comment: The sigma-algebra part baffles me since I would think $\sigma(Y_1, Y_2, ...) = \sigma(Y_1, Y_2, ..., \mathcal{T}_n)$ (since the $X$ values are determined from the $Y$s).  So I would think $\cap_n \sigma(\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{T}_n) = \sigma(\mathcal{F})$. Oh, maybe what I am missing is that hte $\mathcal{F}$ does not include $Y_0$?  Is this intentional, or a typo?

Comment: And if there is indeed a distinction between including $Y_0$ or not, it would help to clarify if $\cap_n$ means an intersection over $n \geq 1$ or $n \geq 0$.  It would also help to define what $\mathcal{Y}$ means.

Comment: @Michael this isnt a typo. I just checked, the question is exactly as stated in the text . I edited the question to include the hint given aswell.

Comment: @Michael although , the Y was  a typo. I corrected that part.

Comment: So does the intersection over $n$ include $n=0$? Writing $\cap_n$ is kind of ambiguous.

Comment: Unfortunately the book does not specify that. I've included the exact picture of the problem aswell now from the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to the independence, start by checking that if $e_0,e_1,\ldots,e_n$ is a fixed sequence of $1$s and $-1$s, then
$$
\cap_{k=0}^n\{X_k=e_k\}=\{Y_0=e_0\}\cap\left[\cap_{k=1}^n\{Y_k=e_{k-1} e_k\}\right]
$$
(because $1/e_k = e_k$ for each $k$).

The key observation for the sigma-algebra assertion is this: For fixed $n\ge 1$,
$$
Y_0=X_n\cdot Y_1\cdot Y_2\cdots Y_n,
$$
from which it follows that $Y_0$ is measurable over $\sigma(X_n,Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)\subset\sigma({\mathcal F},{\mathcal T}_n)$.

Comment: I think you mean $\sigma(X_n, Y_1, ..., Y_n) \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{T}_{n-1})$, since $X_n$ is known from $\mathcal{T}_{n-1}$ but not from $\mathcal{T}_n$.

Comment: Anyway I think the point is that for any $n\geq 0$, $\sigma(\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{T}_{n}) = \sigma(Y_0, Y_1, ...)$, since $Y_0$ can be inferred from $(Y_1, Y_2, ...)$ together with $X_r$ for any particular $r>0$.

Comment: Yes, ${\mathcal T}_{n-1}$.